# The transaction cannot succeed due to error: execution reverted: PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT

Tags: exchanges, bsc, pancakeswap

Why i cant exchange my fckn tokens on pancakeSwap?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to increase slippage in the settings

Comment: i try it, no result

Comment: This error arises when the router cannot give you the requested amount of output tokens for the given input tokens (i.e. slippage is too low or token has an additional transfer fee). You might also want to try it on another BSC dex such as ApeSwap or an aggregator like 1inch (I strongly recommand the latter, since it usually gives you the best possible price).

Comment: 1inch give error too

Comment: in times of high volatility market prices also change faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these were locked tokens, they were blocked by the creators it is something like a scam.